# django dev on mac having to explicitly name full path

Tags: django, osx-yosemite

After a long time away from an app i wrote in Django and didn't complete, I've come back to it on a new Mac.

I'm struggling to get the code to refer to the apps and the files within them without the explicit path. For instance:

```
from myproject.app.file import object
```

Whereas I remember not having to use `myproject` every time.

Is this something that has changed? I seem to remember being about to add to the path in `manage.py` which is called every time you run the dev server, but this hasn't worked this time.

```
sys.path.append /path/to/myproject
```

Should that fix the issue I'm having?

Comment: What's your project/app directory structure? What happens when you use `from app.file import object` or `from .file import object` in a file within the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started with a simple answer and it grew into more details on how to add subdirectories of your project to python path. Maybe a bit off-topic, but it could be useful to you so I'm pushing the post button anyway.

I usually have a bunch of small re-usable apps of mine I keep inside my project tree, because I don't want them to grow into independent modules. My projet tree will look like this:

```
manage.py
myproject/apps
myproject/libs
myproject/settings
...
```

Still, by default, Django only adds the project root to python path. Yet it makes no sense in my opinion to have apps load modules with full path:

```
from myproject.apps.author.models import Author
from myproject.libs.rest_filters import filters
```

That's both way too verbose, and it breaks reusability as I only use absolute imports. Not to mention if I someday build an actual python package out of some of the libs, it will break.

So, I took the following steps. I added the relevant folders to the path:

```
# in manage.py
root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root, 'myproject', 'apps')))
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root, 'myproject', 'libs')))
```

But you must ensure those packages cannot be loaded from the root of the project, or you will have odd issues as python would load another copy of the module. For instance, `isinstance(libs.foo.bar(), myproject.libs.foo.bar) == False`

It's not hard though : just remove `__init__.py` from the folders you add to the path. That will make sure they cannot be descended into from the project.

Also, Django's discover runner will not descend into those paths unless you specify them manually. That may be fine with you (if every module has its own test suite). Or you can extend the runner, so it knows about this: [sample code](https://gist.github.com/spectras/47902eb9344f2e9121f4).

Comment: thanks for the lengthy explanation @spectras. im trying to get this working but i don't think my sys.path.append lines are working. is there a way i can get the sys.path to write out to terminal as i run python manage.py runserver to make sure its appending?

Comment: Yeah well, `sys.stderr.write(str(sys.path))` should work.

Comment: and it did. path was being appended fine, but id forgotten to change the explicit imports to appname only, once i worked that out, i was back in business. thanks for chipping in.